# Use CSS to change hover over text color in shiny navbar

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, navbar

I have created a shiny dashboard using the 'flatly' shiny theme. However, the theme makes my navbar headings turn green when I hover over them. I would prefer them to turn orange instead. I have tried modifying this with custom html code but nothing changes.

[image]

The code I have attempted is:

```
ui <- navbarPage(theme = shinytheme('flatly'), collapsible = TRUE,
                 
                 
                 HTML('<a style="text-decoration:none;cursor:default;color:#FFFFFF;" class="active" href="#">World Happiness Dashboard</a>'), id="nav",
                 
                 tags$head(tags$style('.navbar-nav .nav-item.active .nav-link,
                                      .navbar-nav .nav-item:hover .nav-link {
                                        color:orange;
                                      }')),
                 
                 windowTitle = "World Happiness Dashboard",
```

Answer (score 2):

the best approach to solve your issue will be to do an inspection with browser dev tools on the element you want to change.
at dev tools you will be able to override css properties to your custom and see if it works.
take note at the name of the element (name of the tag where the element is, provably a div), and use it on your css code to override it.

Here what you need:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy to achieve with the `sass` package. Here is a step-by-step approach:

1. Create a SASS file and call it something like `my-style.sass`
2. In the SASS file, add the things you want to change. You'll need to do some digging around in the browser, as suggested by @raOliveira, but for your case, you probably want to add the following:

```
.navbar-default:hover .navbar-nav>li>a:hover
  color: orange

.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover
  color: orange
```

3. Add the folder `www` if you don't have it already.
4. Run this code in the start of your `app.R` file or in your `global.R` file:

```r
library(sass)

sass(
  sass_file("my-style.sass"),
  output = "www/my-style.css"
)
```

This will create a custom CSS based on the SASS file you created.

5. Reference the CSS in your shiny UI:

```r
tags$head(
    tags$link(href = "my-style.css", rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css")
  )
```

#### Reproducible Shiny code

```r
library(shiny)
library(sass)

sass(
  sass_file("my-style.sass"),
  output = "www/my-style.css"
)

ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "test",
  theme = shinythemes::shinytheme('flatly'),
  collapsible = TRUE,
  tags$head(
    tags$link(href = "my-style.css", rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css")
  ),

  tabPanel("Plot"),
  tabPanel("Summary"),
  tabPanel("Table")

)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

#### Output:

The tabs and the title are orange when I hover them:

[image]